# Overlapping Layers

Tags: fme

Currently, all the values overlap each other, I only need whatever layer/value has the highest qpf at any given location. See the attached screenshot as an example. This one shows at the location I clicked on there are 6 layers overlapping that location (1 of 6).

[Overlapping Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwNZY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should clip your polygon layers among them and keep the one with the highest value of your attribute. An AreaOnAreaOverlayer with Accumulation Mode: Use Attributes From One Feature should do the job, but make sure the areas arriving are sorted by your attribute in descending order (i.e. the layers with highest qpf value are last) so the last attributes are kept. If this is not the case you can make use of a Sorter.